# Azure function does not scale up

Tags: python, azure, function

I have built an Azure function which is trigerred when a new blob is added in my storage.
My function works well and trigger whenever I add a new blob into the storage account !

But when I add simultaneously multiple blobs my function does not scale up and process them 1 after another. Do I have to specify a parameter somewhere ?

N.B : My function is mostly sending API request and then wait for an answer (which can take from 5s to 360s). SO the actual % of CPU used is very very low most of the time.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you share the steps that you upload multiple blobs?

I upload multiple blobs with Python like this:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connect_str = ""
container_name = "samples-workitems"
local_file_names = ["httpd-2.4.46-win64-VS16.zip", "downloaded.txt", "New Text Document.txt"]

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
# Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
for local_file_name in local_file_names:
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

    # Upload content to block blob
    with open("D:\\demo\\" + local_file_name, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type="BlockBlob")
```

The trigger logs this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not uploading files using Python at the moment. In fact I drag and drop my files into my container using "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer".
By adding these files my function is triggered. But my function process them one by one instead of starting mùultiple intance to process them in parallel

Comment: The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp) says that “The Blob storage trigger starts a function when **a** new or updated blob is detected”. I think it means the function is triggered one by one when uploading blobs one by one.